# Python, Django: 'Videos' object is not iterable, for video in chunk

Tags: python, django

How to fix that error?

> In template C:\Users\webst\project\webstudio\templates\index.html, error at line 441
> Python: 'Videos' object is not iterable
> This code is not working:

```
439             {% for chunk in videos|slice:":3" %}
440             <div class="row">
441                 {% for video in chunk %}
442                 <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4">
443                     <div class="video-container">
444                         <iframe class="video" src="{{ video.video_id }}" allowfullscreen></iframe>
445                     </div>
446                 </div>
447                 {% endfor %}
448             </div>
449             {% endfor %}
```

This one is working:

```
{% for video in videos %}
            <li>{{ video.video_id }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py is the same:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Videos

def index(request):
    videos = Videos.objects.all()  
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'videos': videos})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code here actually confirms that each entry in the `QuerySet` is not iterable:

```py
{% for video in videos %}
    <li>{{ video.video_id }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

So when you slice the `QuerySet` here, each `chunk` is now just one entry from the sliced `QuerySet` just like `video` is as shown in the above.

Hence `chunk` in the below code represents just one entry gotten from each iteration over the `QuerySet` `Videos.objects.all()`.

```py
{% for chunk in videos|slice:":3" %}
```

**`chunk` is not iterable**. That is why this line throws the errors you got:

```py
{% for video in chunk %}
```